# Cannot Subscript a value of type AnyObject with an index type of String (Swift)

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get users photo from facebook Album. How do i Format this correctly? I tried

```
if let aa = result["photos"] {
  var bb = aa["data"]
}
```

[image]

I want it to be an array. It works find in obj-C though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
if let aa = result["photos"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
  if let bb = aa["data"] as? Array[AnyObject] {
       println(bb)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Amit89 how about this one **img["images"][0]["source"]** ?

Comment: If img["images"] gives an AnyObject, the above thing will not work.